# Restructuring a table with PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am moving my first steps in PowerQuery, so here's my problem. I have a raw data table which list countries and certain products. For each product there is the "market" value followed by a MyValue (meaning my own sales of that product in that country). An example here:

**raw table**
[image: raw table]
What I was trying to obtain with PowerQuery is a table that unpivots the products category and leaves two columns, one for Market and one for MyValue.
I tried in many ways and the closest to the result I could get was splitting the original table in two, one for the Market and one for MyValues. Then unpivot each one of them in PowerQuery so that I could get them in this way:

**Market**
[image: Market]

And

**MyValue**
[image: MyValue]

I tried then to merge the two tables but can't work it out. Of course I could do that manually but I'm sure there a way to do it with PowerQuery, either splitting into 2 tables, unpivoting and then merging or - even better - with a single query.
The result I'm aiming at is like

**Desired Result**
[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

You are close.

After you unpivot, you need to create a custom column that you can pivot on, and also modify the names in the resultant "attribute" column.

Read the comments in the code and explore the Applied Steps window to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="rawTable"]}[Content],

//generalized "typer" in case you add other Items
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Country", type text}, {"Date", type date}} & 
        List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2),each {_, Int64.Type})),

//Unpivot all except Country|Date        
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Country", "Date"}, "Item", "Value"),

//Add Custom Column to create Pivot column for "Market" and "MyValue
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Custom", each 
        if Text.StartsWith([Item],"My") 
        then "Market" 
        else "MyValue"),

//Replace "My" so Item Labels will be consistent
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom","My","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Item"}),


//Pivot with no aggregation (unless you want to)
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Replaced Value", List.Distinct(#"Replaced Value"[Custom]), "Custom", "Value"),

//Sort "Items" to original Column Order
    itemSortOrder = List.Distinct(#"Replaced Value"[Item]),
    sorted = Table.Sort(#"Pivoted Column",
        {{"Country", Order.Ascending},
        each List.PositionOf(itemSortOrder,[Item])
        })    
in
    sorted
```

Hopefully, this is what you want for a result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for having spent your time to help me.

I think I solved my problem using the List.Zip function. Solution was not mine but I took if from [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1O5LfMZP0s) video. With this trick, I don't even have to split the original source data into two tables (market & MyShare).

It perfectly does what I needed to with little if no effort for data-cleaning...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).